# Configure pylint for modules within eggs. (VS code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

#### Project structure

I have the following folder structure

```
|
|- src
|   |- mypackage
|   |    |- __init__.py
|   |    |- mymodule.py
|   |- utils.egg
|- main.py
```

in `mymodule.py` file I can import the egg adding it to the `sys.path` as

```
import sys
sys.path.append('src/utils.egg')
import utils
```

When calling `main.py` everything works fine (`python -m main`).

#### Problem

The problem comes from `pylint`. First, it shows the following message in `mymodule.py` file

> Unable to import 'utils' pylint(import-error)

if I ask for suggestions (`CRTL + Space`) when importing I got

```
utils.build
     .dist
     .utils
     .setup
#     |- suggestions
```

And from `utils.utils` I can acces the actual classes / functions in `utils` module. Of course if I import `utils.utils`, when executing the `main` script, an importing error pops up.

- How can I configure my vscode setting in order fix pylint?
- should I install the egg instead of copy it to the working folder?
- Is my project's folder-structure ok, or it goes against recommended practices?

#### Extra info

In case you wonder the `EGG-INFO/SOURCE.txt` file looks like

```
setup.py
utils/__init__.py
utils/functions.py
utils.egg-info/PKG-INFO
utils.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
utils.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
utils.egg-info/top_level.txt
utils/internals/__init__.py
utils/internals/somemodule.py
utils/internals/someothermodule.py
```

Also, there aren't `build` nor `dist` folder in the egg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Pylint itself and not the Python extension, so it will come down to however you need to configure Pylint.

As for whether you should copy an egg around or install it, you should be installing it into your virtual environment, or at least copying over the appropriate `.pth` file to make the egg directory work appropriately.